# Arrange numbers in order

Tags: variables, numbers

I've some variables, Lets say a, b, c, d. All belongs to a fixed interval [0, e]
Now i've some relations between them like

```
a > b
a > c
b > d
```

Something like this; I want to make a function which print all the possible cases for this.

Example:

```
a b c d 
a c b d
a b d c
a c b d
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code at all? If you haven't yet started, put the code aside for the time being and think about the logic. If you were to answer this question by hand and on paper, and would you go about it? Then convert your process into code.

Comment: Yea i put some efforts in thinking of logics.
Like i will assign points to every variable.
starting from first relation
say a = 1, now b is less than a so let say i assigned 2 to b.
same for c, while for d i assign 2 + 1 = 3
Hence
a = 1
b = 2
c = 2
d = 3
Now this gives me idea that for the position 2 we have 2 variables hence i can swap them. But this logic lacks for variable d.

Comment: I also thought to use the concept of tree.
where each child represents that this child is less than its parent node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, what you have is a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

A relatively simple approach is to store, for each variable, a set of the variables that *must* precede them. (In your example, this storage would map `b` to `{a}`, `c` to `{a}`, and `d` to `{b}`.) You can then write a recursive function that generates all valid *tails* consisting of a subset of these variables (in your case, for example, the subset `{c,d}` produces two valid tails: `[c,d]` and `[d,c]`). This recursive function examines each variable in the subset and determines whether its prerequisites are already met. (For example, since `b` maps to `{a}`, any subset including both `a` and `b` cannot produce a tail that begins with `b`.) If so, then it can recursively call itself on the subset excluding that variable.

There are some optimizations you can then perform, if desired. For example, you can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to avoid repeatedly re-computing the set of valid tails for the same subset.